# Difference between "Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine" and "Google Protocol RPC Library" for App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm looking for ways to expose business logic that I've implemented in a Google App Engine application as an RPC service for mobile clients to call; there seem to be two ways of doing this:

- [Google Protocol RPC Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/protorpc/) for App Engine. The examples there had me create a WSGI service using `protorpc.wsgi.service.service_mapping` exposing service classes whose methods are decorated with `protorpc.remote.method`.
- [Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api). The examples there had me create a Cloud Endpoint using `endpoints.api_server` exposing service classes whose methods are decorated with `endpoints.method`.

I started with Google Protocol RPC library because that was the main thing that was linked from the App Engine documentation, and got the RPC working, which I can verify with a simple `curl` command. But I could not find how to generate Android / iOS client libraries.

After searching longer, I found Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine, which seems to be offering the option to generate Android / iOS libraries, but I'm confused by the similarities between the two options (e.g. it seems that Cloud Endpoints Framework relies at least partly on protorpc as well, but the decorators and handlers are different) and am unsure which one I should be choosing.

(NB: I understand that Cloud Endpoints are available for more environments, such as Compute Engine, but *I want to stay in App Engine standard as much as possible*.)

My questions:

1. *Can someone articulate the differences between these two seemingly very similar solutions?* What are some situations in which I might prefer using the Google Protocol RPC library over the Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine? What are some of the other situations in which Cloud Endpoints Framework is preferable?
2. *Is there a way to generate client libraries from API definitions written for the Google Protocol RPC library?* Now that I've gotten the simple Google Protocol RPC library version working, I'm not sure I should do the work to migrate over to Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine just for the benefit of client code generation.